# Expected number of empty boxes, placing m balls into n boxes

Tags: combinatorics

$m$ balls are placed into $n$ boxes at random with uniform probability. What is the expected number of empty boxes?

The link below presents the solution for the case when $m = n$. Unfortunately, I do not understand the solution sufficiently to extend it to the non-equal case.

[Find: The expected number of urns that are empty](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396828/find-the-expected-number-of-urns-that-are-empty)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By linearity of expectation, the answer is $n$ (the number of boxes) times
the probability that a given box remains empty (that is $(1-1/n)^m$).

I'm assuming the positions are independent.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer makes sense, but it does not reduce to the linked answer when $n=m$. Does that mean that the linked answer is wrong?

Comment: The linked problem is **different** @AleksejsFomins

Comment: I fail to see how. The objects are labelled, but it is explicitly stated in the solution that it is irrelevant. If we were to take the special case $m=n$, how is my problem different from the linked problem?

Comment: In the linked problem, the first ball can go into the first box. The second ball can go into the first or the second box. The third can go into the first, second, or third box, and so on.

Comment: Ufff, I did not notice difference in range between random variables originally. Thanks :)